# How do I unmarshal JSON into empty struct from function without loosing type?

Tags: json, go

I have a question about JSON unmarshalling. I use a method to retrieve an empty struct based on a key. The return type of this method is of course `interface{}` and I pass this empty struct to `json.Unmarshal()`. The problem I have is that the type is lost after unmarshalling.

I wrote an example of this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

const (
    messageWithQuotes    = "{\"a\": \"Hello World!\"}"
)

func main() {
    fromMethodWithQuotes := unmarshalSomeStuff(messageWithQuotes)
    fmt.Printf("from method with quotes:    %s\n", reflect.TypeOf(fromMethodWithQuotes).String())
    directlyWithQuotes := unmarshalSomeStuffDirectly(messageWithQuotes)
    fmt.Printf("directly with quotes:       %s\n", reflect.TypeOf(directlyWithQuotes).String())
}

type MessageContainer1 struct {
    A string `json:"a"`
}

type MessageContainer2 struct {
    Another string `json:"another"`
}

// createMessageContainerForType retrieves an empty struct that matches the passed type.
func createMessageContainerForType(msgType string) interface{} {
    var res interface{}
    switch msgType {
    case "type-1":
        res = MessageContainer1{}
    case "type-2":
        res = MessageContainer2{}
    }
    return res
}

// unmarshalSomeStuff uses the given message, and an empty struct from createMessageContainerForType.
func unmarshalSomeStuff(message string) interface{} {
    emptyContainer := createMessageContainerForType("type-1")
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(message), &emptyContainer); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    return emptyContainer
}

// unmarshalSomeStuffDirectly uses the given message but assumes that we use type 1 message.
func unmarshalSomeStuffDirectly(message string) interface{} {
    specificEmptyContainer := MessageContainer1{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(message), &specificEmptyContainer); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    return specificEmptyContainer
}
```

The output I get is

```
from method with quotes:    map[string]interface {}
directly with quotes:       main.MessageContainer1
```

Is there any way to avoid the generic `map[string]interface {}` for that? I know I could create a large switch case and then do the unmarshalling directly there but I wanted to separate this functionality for cleaner code and I am fairly new to go but still can't find a solution.

Thanks for any help or the information that this has already been asked in hundreds of threads ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a pointer to the target value instead of the value.

```
func createMessageContainerForType(msgType string) interface{} {
    var res interface{}
    switch msgType {
    case "type-1":
        res = &MessageContainer1{}  // <-- note change to pointer return value
    case "type-2":
        res = &MessageContainer2{}  // <-- note change to pointer return value
    }
    return res
}
```

Do not take the address of the container in `unmarshalSomeStuff`:

```
func unmarshalSomeStuff(message string) interface{} {
    emptyContainer := createMessageContainerForType("type-1")
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(message), emptyContainer); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    return emptyContainer
}
```

[Run it on the official Go Language Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/lSYptxjsU0h).

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked. I thought this information would be kept so I did not think about that. Thank you!